# LinkedHashMap vs ArrayList with Bluetooth Scanning and ListView

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have a little bit of a confusion when it comes to what is considered the better implementation.

One the one hand,

`LinkedHashMap` provides the following benefits:

1. Prevents duplicate items (I need to be able to prevent a scanned Bluetooth device to not repeatedly enter the list.)
2. Provides easy access to items for updating values.

And the following pitfalls:

1. Not supported naturally by the `BaseAdapter` class? I cannot seem to retrieve elements using `getItem` for a custom `ListView` `Adapter`.

However with an `ArrayList`

1. I can easily access items via their indices.
2. Can easily replace items for updating values.
3. Works easily with custom `BaseAdapter` class.
   But...
4. I receive duplicated items.
5. I cannot easily compare or check with the `ArrayList.contains` method unless I implement some custom `comparators` of the `ArrayList`'s objects' parameters.

Is there an easier way to achieve the following:

1. Scan via BLE, construct a custom object from the scan results. (already complete).
2. Stick that custom object in an array list if it isn't already in it.
3. If it is already in the array list, replace the previous object with the new one?

Comment: What about using a `Set` or override the `add()` of your `List` to only add if its not in there? I also fail to see why you are comparing a `Map` and a `List`. Seems to me like apple and oranges

Comment: @user489041 I need order, a set does not guarantee order does it? The reason I am comparing the two is because I am not entirely certain on which would be better for the final bit of my implementation. I have done research on quite a bit but have not found much describing what to do in this particular situation.

Comment: ArrayList.contains uses internally Object.equals. So you could override equals and hash , implementing comparable and in conjunction with contains and Collections.sort you have everything you need.

Comment: @user489041, how I mean is. If I take the ArrayList approach. How come my ArrayList.contains(object) is always returning false, and duplicating those scans? This would imply I need to use a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: @Tukajo `LinkedHashSet` guarantees order - it is the order in which elements are added to the set.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re What you stated ended up working for me. If you submit it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody seems to answer, I will provide my approach.

**1. Duplicated entries**

If you like to use a *List* , then as I stated out in the comments,
I would let your Item class override `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()`.
These are used internally in `ArrayList.contains()`. 
This would give you no duplicated entries with adding only items where
`list.contains(item) == false`.

**2. Sorting**

To sort a List, there is the very usefull class called *Collections*, which
sorts a list simply with the static method `Collections.sort()`.
To make this work you need to implement the *Comparable* interface in your 
item class and apply your own sorting rules here.

**TreeSet**

If it does not necessarily needs to be a List, I would recommend to 
implement *Comparable* and use a TreeSet, which gives you by the nature
of a set no duplicated entries and is sorted directly by adding.

**LinkedHashSet**

If you only need no duplicated entries and the order should followed
by the order of insertion, go with LinkedHashSet.

Best wishes, Steve.